# Powershell parsing of command in a string

Tags: powershell

In a powershell script, I have a command in the form of a string. I would like to know if there an easy way to extract the arguments in the form of a hashmap.

Input :

```
$str = "SampleCommandName -Arg1 Value1 -Arg2 Value2"
$command, $parameters = Some-Function $str
Write-Host $parameters[Arg1]
```

Output : Value1

I tried using ConvertFrom-StringData, but my version of PowerShell does not support Delimiter parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert that to a hash manually:

```
$str = "SampleCommandName -Arg1 Value1 -Arg2 Value2"

$hash = [ordered]@{}
$str.Split("-").Trim() | Where-Object { $_.Contains(" ") } | ForEach-Object { 
    $name, $value = $_ -split '\s+', 2
    $hash[$name] = $value
}

$hash
```

Or you can use `ConvertFrom-StringData` and a regex replace to change the space between the name and value into a `=` character.
You need to make sure that it only replaces the first occurrence, in order not to interfere with any spaces in the values.

```
$str = "SampleCommandName -Arg1 Value1 -Arg2 Value2"
($str.Split("-").Trim() | Where-Object { $_.Contains(" ") }) -replace '([^\s]+)\s(.*)', '$1=$2' -join "`r`n" | ConvertFrom-StringData
```

Alternative without regex:

```
$str = "SampleCommandName -Arg1 Value1 -Arg2 Value2"
($str.Split("-").Trim() | Where-Object { $_.Contains(" ") } | ForEach-Object { $_.Split(' ', 2) -join '=' }) -join "`r`n" | ConvertFrom-StringData
```

Output:

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                     
----                           -----                                                                                                                                     
Arg1                           Value1                                                                                                                                    
Arg2                           Value2
```